# Use angularjs to fetch data in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, angularjs-directive

I've a simple question/answer app built on laravel. When a user adds a new question, the question gets displayed on the dashboard page.

Sample dashboard view-

```
Welcome John!

 - This is first question
 - This is second question
```

This is done using laravel only. Now I want to fetch and display answers under each question respectively using angular only, this way:

```
Welcome John!

 - This is first question
   -answer 1
   -answer 2
 - This is second question 
   -answer 1
   -answer 2
```

Since all the answers part should be done using angularjs and that too on page load, how can I let angularjs know which answers to fetch and where to display

I tried the following approach using directives

```
@section('list-questions')
    <ul>
        @foreach($listQuestions as $q)
            <li><a href="{{url('/questions/'.$q->question_id)}}">{{ $q->question }}</a></li>
            <getAnswers ng-model="qid" ng-init="qid='{{$q->question_id}}'"></getAnswers>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

I'm trying to get 'ID' of each question and then pass it to controller, use `$http.get` and show it using directives, but I'm unable to pick the ng-model value, is there any other way or how should I fix this?

Comment: Can I see your angularjs code

Comment: Post you angular codes.